# All values null when submit button clicked from a created form

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I'm trying to get the value from form and when I debug it, it shows me only null. Is there any thing wrong with my binding request? Or something else?

create.scala.index:

```
@(bookform : Form[Book])
@import helper._
<html>
<head>
    <title>Create Book</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>All Books</h1>

    @helper.form(CSRF(routes.BooksController.save())){
        @helper.inputText(bookform("id"))
        @helper.inputText(bookform("title"))
        @helper.inputText(bookform("price"))
        @helper.inputText(bookform("author"))

        <input type="submit" value="create book">
    }
```

BookController.java:

```
import views.html.books.*;
import javax.inject.Inject;
public class BooksController extends Controller {

    //help to create forms
    @Inject
    FormFactory formFactory;

    //for all book
    public Result index(){
        Set<Book> books= Book.allBook();
        return  ok(index.render(books));
    }

    //create book
    public Result create(){
        Form<Book> bookForm = formFactory.form(Book.class);
        return  ok(create.render(bookForm));
    }

    //to save book
    public Result save(){
        Form<Book> bookForm=formFactory.form(Book.class).bindFromRequest();
        Book book1= bookForm.get();
        Book.add(book1);

        return  redirect(routes.BooksController.index());
    } 
}
```

Book.java:

```
public static Set<Book> allBook(){
    return books;
}

public static void add(Book book){
    books.add(book);
}
```

Comment: Can you add the whole code of Book.java class?

Comment: Sure i'll do that

Comment: Are you using [play-enhancer](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/PlayEnhancer)?

Comment: No i didint use

Answer (score 0):

**This is my whole book.java class**

```
package models;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Book {
public Integer id;
public String title;
public Integer price;
public String author;

public Book() {

}

public Book(Integer id, String title, Integer price, String author) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.price = price;
    this.author = author;
}

private static Set<Book> books;

static {
    books= new HashSet<>();
    books.add(new Book(1,"C++",1100,"Abc"));
    books.add(new Book(2,"JAVA",1100,"Scd"));

}

public static Set<Book> allBook(){
    return books;
}

public static Book findById(Integer id){
    for(Book books:books) {
        if (id.equals(books.id)){
            return books;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public static void add(Book book){
    books.add(book);
}

public static boolean remove(Book book){
    return books.remove(book);
}
```

}